# problems running a php script from crontab

Tags: php, cron

I have been googling a lot in order to see if someone had a similar problem. Well I like to run a php script from my crontab.
The crontab entry looks like:

```
*   *   * * * /usr/bin/php5 -f /home/antoine/Dropbox/ALC/test.php
```

but nothing happens, in my syslog I see the following entry:

> Mar  7 20:39:01 london CRON[7169]: (antoine) CMD (/usr/bin/php5 -f /home/antoine/Dropbox/ALC/test.php)

If I run the command from the command line, then all goes well. The test.php script just creates a files and writes my name to it.

If I use a bash script with a similar functionality then all works via cron; i.e. the file is created etc.

I don't like to use curl and rewrite the script so that it can be run from in that way as I think that this is a security risk.

Any suggestions are welcome,

thanks,
 Antoine

Comment: It probably has something to do with the paths you are using in the PHP file.  You should use absolute paths in the PHP file when writing to the file.

Comment: Look in the error_log

Comment: Debug, debug! You could do something like this: 'su -'. Then cd to the same directory where your test.php file is 'cd /var/www/project/public_html/'. Then run the file 'php -f test.php'. If this works better, just write all these commands to the crontab line.

Comment: @viljun Hi, i've followed your comment and it works when I run the scrip from the command line. But it does not work when calling the file from within the crontab line. Any thoughts?